# Using Jest to test scripts affecting the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, testing, dom, jestjs

I have a script that translated markdown to html on a document and I'm trying to test the html rending. Here's what I have so far.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/oscarmorrison/md-page/master/md-page.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript># hello</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my Jest file.

```js
describe("HTML Rendering Tests: Ensures that syntax is converted successfully.", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://rawcdn.githack.com/oscarmorrison/md-page/master/md-page.js";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  });

  test('it should load scripts', () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<noscript># hello';
    expect(document.body).toContain('Hello');
  });
});
```

I've printed everything inside  it doesn't seem to be translating the text to markdown. Any thoughts?

```html
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/oscarmorrison/md-page/master/md-page.js"></script></head><body><noscript># hello</noscript></body>
```

Comment: Are you testing the script or your markup? You cannot expect the script to be loaded synchronously. It's also unclear why you load the script remotely.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm planning to test resulting markup, so # hello should translate to <h1> hello </h1>. I didn't build the script (I'm using md-page), I want to test that the script translates properly

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of this. If you've got a markdown to test, use a straightforward way with least moving parts. md-page seems to use `showdown`. Render with it. If you insist on using md-page for some reason, get a local copy at least. Doing async requests to githacks server for no good reason makes the test sluggish and unreliable. Using md-page will likely require a new JSDOM instance instead of Jest's default one, and load event needs to be waited manually, e.g. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914#issuecomment-313786743 , it cannot work synchronously like you tried it.

Comment: @EstusFlask That's interesting, and forgive me for the obvious questions here (I'm a junior engineer looking to write tests for an open source project). I can import showdown to my jest file but what do you mean by "render with it"?

Comment: If you don't have a specific requirement to test it with md-page script then yes, doing this with showdown will likely be simpler. The way it needs to be tested depends in which form you have a markdown to test, e.g. `expect(new showdown.Converter().makeHtml(myMdSnippet)).toBe('...')`. Jest snapshots may be simpler for markup tests than string assertions, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing . Verify manually that a markup conforms your expectations in .snap file once and leave it be.

Comment: That's super helpful, thank you @EstusFlask!